# Clojure practice - use functions of complex datatypes or their elements?

Tags: function, clojure, lisp, composition

It is idiomatic in lisps such as Clojure to use simple data-structures and lots of functions.  Still, there are many times when we must work with complex data-structures composed of many simpler ones.

My question is about a matter of good style/practice.  **In general, should we create functions that take the entire complex object, and within that extract what we need, or should they take exactly and only what they need?**

For concreteness, I compare these two options in the following psuedo code

```
(defrecord Thing
  [a b])

(defn one-option
  [a]
  .. a .. ))

(one-option (:a a-thing))

;; ==============

(defn another-option
  [a-thing]
  .. (:a a-thing) .. ))
```

The pros of `one-option-f` is that the function is simpler, and has fewer responsibilities.  It is also more compositional - it can be used in more places.

The downside is that we may end up repeating ourselves.  If, for example, we have many functions which transform one `Thing` into another `Thing`, many of which need use `one-option`, within each one we will find ourselves repeating the extraction code.  Of course, another option is to create both, but this also adds a certain code overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is *"It depends"* and *"It doesn't matter as much in Clojure as it does in object systems"*. Clojure has a number of largely orthogonal mechanisms designed to express modes of composition. The granularity of function arguments will tend to fall out of how the structure of the program is conceived of in the large.

---

So much for the hot air. There are some specifics that can affect argument granularity:

- Since Clojure data structures are immutable, data hiding and access
  functions/methods have little relevance. So the repetition caused by
  accessing parts of a complex structure is trifling.
- What appear in object-design as associations are rendered by small
  collections of typed object pointers in each object. In Clojure,
  these tend to become single(ton) global maps. There are a standard
  Clojure functions for accessing and manipulating hierarchical
  structures of this kind (`get-in` and `assoc-in`, for examples).
- Where we are looking for dynamically-bound compliance with an
  interface, Clojure protocols and datatypes are cleaner and more
  adaptable than most object systems. In this case, the whole object is
  passed.

Answer (score 0):

Do both. To begin with, provide functions that transform the simplest structures, then add convenience functions for handling more complex structures which compose the functions that handle the simple ones.